# Display the top 10 highest `player name` with their `coins` in order from greatest to lowest

Tags: php, mysql

I need help displaying the `players name` and their `coins` in order. I currently have

```
$SQL = $odb -> query("SELECT SUM(kills) AS `kills` FROM `players` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 0,10");

$SQL -> execute();
echo $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
```

But that sends back 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query, right now its summing the total of kills inside players table :

```
$SQL = $odb -> query("SELECT player_name,SUM(kills) AS `kills`
                      FROM `players`
                      GROUP BY player_name
                      ORDER BY `kills` DESC
                      LIMIT 10");
```

I assumed you have a column named player_name, if not change it to your true column name.

You are just echoing the first column, which is the player name so you can echo the second one as well

```
echo $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
echo $SQL -> fetchColumn(1);
```

Comment: Hai! thanks so much but it only returns then players name :/

Comment: @AlexPlue Just change the echo to column(1) and not column(0) .. You have two columns now

Comment: it now only displays the kills

Comment: I have also echoed `echo $SQL -> fetchColumn(1);`

Comment: Ok thanks this has worked goos for now. But it only says there is 1 player with kills instead of 10

Comment: Because you are displaying only the first row.

Comment: How do i display 10 of them.

Comment: How would i make it display 10 players?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so far i have this

`$SQL = $odb -> query("SELECT username,SUM(kills) AS`kills
`FROM`players
`GROUP BY username
ORDER BY`kills`DESC
LIMIT 10");`

`$SQL -> execute();
echo $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
echo $SQL -> fetchColumn(1);`

And it only says 1 player i need to make it 10 man.